# Why python function return different result with same argument?

Tags: python

```
def dbl_linear(n):

    integers = [1]
    for k in range(71100):
        integers.extend([integers[k]*2+1, integers[k] * 3 + 1])
    a = list(set(integers))
    a.sort()
    return a[n]
```

I found this task at codewars, but can't solve it
My function return different result It's depending on number in range
If i wrote in range 60001 and return list[60000] and if i wrote in range 100000 and return list[60000] they are different
Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generate numbers that are *not strictly ordered*. For every increase in `k`, *two* more integers are added to the list that are not necessarily greater than the numbers added before.

You see this at `k = 2` already:

- For `k = 0`, `integers[0]` is `1`, so the loop adds `1 * 2 + 1` and `1 * 3 + 1` == `3, 4`.
- `k = 1` takes `integers[1]` == `3`, so adds `7, 10` to the list.
- `k = 2` takes `integers[2]` == `4`, so adds `9, 13` to the list. `9` is *lower* than `10`

This continues onwards as you repeatedly add more values. For `10001` repeats the loop evidently adds *at least one* value that is smaller than the value that was sorted into index `60000` when you repeated the loop only `60001` times.

There are, in fact, 3001 such values:

```
>>> upto60k = [1]
>>> for k in range(60001):
...     upto60k += upto60k[k] * 2 + 1, upto60k[k] * 3 + 1
...
>>> upto100k = [1]
>>> for k in range(100001):
...     upto100k += upto100k[k] * 2 + 1, upto100k[k] * 3 + 1
...
>>> added = sorted(set(upto100k).difference(upto60k))
>>> len(added)
68046
>>> sorted(set(upto60k))[60000]
1726840
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> bisect_left(added, 1726840)  # index of first value > 1726840
3001
```

So 3001 of the extra values added to `integers` in the longer loop are smaller than  `1726840` and would be sorted before that value; so you'll find the same `1726840` value in the 100k repeat set at index 63001:

```
>>> sorted(set(upto100k))[63001]
1726840
```

Comment: @Korifa: solve *what* exactly? You haven't given us any information on the actual problem. Note that you'd ask a new question about that though.